# numpy much slower on cluster than Desktop

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I've installed numpy on my server and linked with the below libraries and python:

```
Python-2.7.9
Numpy-1.9.2
OpenBlas-0.2.10
Atlas
```

Openblas with or without numpy is giving the same result in my server.

But my runs on my desktop are much faster than on the HPC server. More >details below:
On server below results:

```
import numpy as np
import time
A=np.random.random((1000,1000))
B=np.random.random((1000,1000))
t=time.time();np.dot(A,B);print time.time()-t
array([[ 244.68742139,  248.06278415,  243.8470716 , ...,  237.00600025,
         246.48968543,  243.30411108],
       [ 245.53309606,  240.93001932,  242.07282106, ...,  234.61134087,
         246.8035772 ,  240.08430753],
       [ 251.26426555,  250.28870749,  243.7012242 , ...,  238.03493551,
         245.19529261,  242.56134817],
       ...,
       [ 253.50021674,  254.2082562 ,  253.28257115, ...,  248.79910477,
         255.83380586,  255.79587693],
       [ 255.17478038,  254.54329655,  246.4440345 , ...,  239.20522728,
         253.42703832,  248.55475779],
       [ 255.54552176,  252.53394451,  249.27373006, ...,  245.36860788,
         254.46053394,  247.16377842]])
1.54565000534
```

On my computer, I get the following output

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import time
>>> A=np.random.random((1000,1000))
>>> B=np.random.random((1000,1000))
>>> t=time.time();np.dot(A,B);print time.time()-t
array([[ 251.02325661,  247.76487062,  243.96296321, ...,  247.74526818,
         240.01351009,  242.09309446],
       [ 244.70605416,  237.32349381,  243.15063794, ...,  248.87322205,
         235.37442193,  234.0516297 ],
       [ 244.75370599,  241.37853315,  244.81765191, ...,  245.14608767,
         232.0443932 ,  238.92630488],
       ...,
       [ 257.63017911,  253.70984268,  250.2429554 , ...,  258.54986519,
         244.67368682,  242.91374959],
       [ 252.534875  ,  243.55947921,  244.91385322, ...,  246.52761375,
         232.01807853,  240.7038384 ],
       [ 243.48345396,  238.21551591,  241.92045466, ...,  244.55678965,
         228.53646839,  241.20027957]])
0.155517101288
```

---

Details of Workstation machine:

```
Processor: x8
processor : 0
vendor_id  : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model      : 58
model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping   : 9
microcode  : 0x1b
cpu MHz         : 3833.234
cache size : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings   : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores  : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu        : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp         : yes
flags      : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov >pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm >constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc >aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 >cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave >avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi >flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt
bugs       :
bogomips   : 6784.77
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

Memory:
Size: 8192 MB
     Form Factor: DIMM
     Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
     Bank Locator: BANK 0
     Type: DDR3
     Type Detail: Synchronous
     Speed: 1600 MHz

Hard Disk :
[1.00 TB]SATA
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
```

Details of Cluster server:

```
Processor:
processor       : 23
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 62
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz
stepping        : 4
cpu MHz         : 1200.000
cache size      : 30720 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 12
core id         : 13
cpu cores       : 12
apicid          : 58
initial apicid  : 58
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca >cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx >pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology >nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 >cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave >avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi >flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips        : 5386.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

Memory:
Size: 16384 MB
Form Factor: DIMM
Locator: PROC  2 DIMM  8
Type: DDR3
Speed: 1866 MHz
```

Comment: i7 3770 are pretty fast for single thread performance

Comment: so are  E5-2697 (well maybe marginally slower according to cpubenchmark). Still, this has probably something to do with either OpenBlas being incorrectly linked on the cluster to numpy or using different compilation flags and/or complier on both machines.

Comment: try a more computation intensive task. you should think of the communication cost between nodes in the cluster and the main host (sending and receiving the data).